# how to call from an azure web app a process running as a continuous azure webjob

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

I want to run the OPA (https://www.openpolicyagent.org/) agent as a background process besides my webapp with my webapp calling the OPA agent through http://localhost:8181.

I can start the OPA agent (with opa.exe run -s) which exposes an API on localhost:8181 through a continuous webjob in the azure web app.
However, my web app cannot connect to the OPA agent.

Is it possible for a web app process to do RPC (REST API) with a webjob process ?

Comment: Have you verified that your web job is running successfully? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create#ViewJobHistory

Comment: Yes, it is running and listening to the port (according to the logs of the process displayed in the webjobs logs)